# MySQL Left Join with WHERE and Greater than

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

I want to do a `LEFT JOIN` and then sort my display by a `rank` column and also show items only if the `qty` column is greater than 0

```
SELECT 
*
FROM `product`
LEFT JOIN `stock`
ON `product`.`product_id`=`stock`.`pid`
AND `qty` > 1
ORDER BY `product`.`rank` ASC
```

**Product Table**

```
product_id
name
rank
price
```

**Stock Table**

```
pid
price_sale
qty

Product Table

12, Pen, 2, 53.00
13, Pen, 1, 58.00
14, Pen, 3, 25.00

Stock Table

12, 10.00, 5 
13, 18.00, 15
```

My results do not appear.

It should display:

```
12, Pen, 2, 53.00, 12, 10.00, 5
13, Pen, 1, 58.00, 13, 18.00, 15
```

Comment: Replace `LEFT JOIN` with `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: The SQL looks like it should work (but without the suggestion by @ypercube it will bring back nulls for the stock table columns for rows where the qty is not greater than 1). What are the data types of the columns?

Comment: You are not asking for the 'stock' table to provided in your resultset, ie `SELECT * FROM products, s LEFT JOIN stock as s ON s.qty > 0 [...]`. Also, ORDER BY should only be used with fields you specifically request (product.rank).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Below Query

```
SELECT * FROM `product`
LEFT JOIN `stock`
ON `product`.`product_id`=`stock`.`pid`
WHERE `stock`.`qty` > 0
ORDER BY `product`.`rank` ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

The AND should be a WHERE like this :

```
SELECT *
FROM `product`
LEFT JOIN `stock` ON `product`.`product_id`=`stock`.`pid`
WHERE `qty` > 1
ORDER BY `product`.`rank` ASC
```